# Access random object on parsing JSON via combined variable

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm having a very simple JSON file which looks like:

```
{
 "seasons" : {
    "s_1" : {
        "episodes" : 7
    },
    "s_2" : {
        "episodes" : 21
    },
    "s_3" : {
        "episodes" : 22
    },
    "s_4" : {
        "episodes" : 30
    },
    "s_5" : {
        "episodes" : 18
    },
    "s_6" : {
        "episodes" : 12
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to randomly select a `s_ x` value from seasons when parsing the file:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data) {         
        console.log(data.seasons.s_+random);
    });
```

this obviously does not work. How would be the correct way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
console.log(data.seasons["s_"+random]);
```

Using brackets so it becomes something like data.seasons["s_1"]

Comment: it does! I'm just wondering why you can miss the point there.

Comment: @supersize: Simply because that's how the syntax is defined. A property can either be accessed using dot (`foo.bar`) or bracket notation (`foo['bar']`).

Comment: Because the way it's listed would induce a different kind of error.  data.seasons.s_+random would give an undefined error wouldn't it?  When you look for data.seasons.s_ (undefined) and try to concatenate/add random to it.

Comment: @MingShun: It would not throw an error. The result would be `NaN` (e.g. `undefined + 1`).

Comment: Why not just attach a "length" property on the same level as s_1, s_2, s_3 to the json file?  Then generate the random number with it.

Comment: @Felix Kling:  Thanks!  I'm getting confused with all of the errors that can pop up between PHP, Javascript, and MySQL.  I'll try and remember this.